# Add File version, Product Version to the Existing Assemblies

Tags: assemblies, reference, clr, cil

I have some set of assemblies. I have disassemble those assemblies using the ISDASM.exe and change the namespace in the IL code and again compile those IL code using the ISASM.exe to get the assemblies without any error.

Here my question is after disassemble and assemble those assemblies product version, File version and the copyright information is lost. How can i add the File version and Product version after creating the assemblies.

But in the disassemble IL code all the version information are avaliable. But after compiling the IL code version information are not there.

Thanks,
Velu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things, you'll have to create  [a version file resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa381058), and include it with the `/resource` option.